# How to use REGEX inside of an if statement

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I need to create a code where i take all the files in the current directory ending with *.txt, *.jpg, *.conf. After i collect those i need to check if they contain a certain line which is: 
 `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

if they do contain the following line, then i need to rename them to *.xml.

My question is: How do i check with regex in an if statement if the file contains the given regex code?

My current code:

```
ls *.txt *.data *.conf
for f in *.*
case $f in
*.txt)
if [[ "$(grep -q '<\?xml version="[0-9]*.[0-9]*" encoding=".*"\?>' *.txt) ]]; then
mv -- "$f" "${%f.txt].xml"
fi
;;

esac
done
ls
```

the code for *.jpg) and *.conf) would be the same. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use:

```
for f in *.txt *.data *.conf; do
   if grep -iq '<?xml version="[0-9]*\.[0-9]*" encoding="[^"]*"?>' "$f"; then
      mv "$f" "${f%.*}.xml" 
   fi
done
```

`-q` option in `grep` is for the quiet mode.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i probably forgot to state that the files can have different versions and encodings.